# Heroku process.env not showing config vars

Tags: javascript, heroku, config

I have a react app in a Heroku pipeline.  Simply staging -> production.

In staging => Settings I have some config vars set up for the environment.  However, when I `console.log(process.env)` I do not see them.

Am I supposed to be able to access these config vars in this manner?  From what I've read, I should be able to access them from `process.env`.  No?

Answer (score 4):

I am using the following buildpack: `https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack.git`

Apparently you MUST name the config vars starting with `REACT_APP_` and then you can access them via `process.env`.

This is all clearly outlined in the buildpack's documentation.  I was just too dumb to actually check there :/

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but changing the variable names to begin with REACT_APP_ didn't fix it, I still cannot access my config vars from process.env

Answer (score 0):

Append your Config Var name with the string '**React_App_**' at the beginning (like React_App_Var_Name) and use this name in your ReactJs app. If this string is not appended and used, then it will return *undefined*.

For deploying production build, follow the steps mentioned in [this](https://dev.to/niinpatel/comment/5b6p) link.