# heroku environment variables return undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku

I tried to set some env. variables on Heroku and I did, I can see the variables in the app when opening the Heroku dashboard. But When I try to access the variables from my app it return `undefined` any idea?

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log('this env' , process.env.backEndServer) // undefined
}
```

checking in the Heroku cli:

```
$ heroku config:get backEndServer // https://myserver.com
```

Comment: Interesting. Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47561604/heroku-process-env-not-showing-config-vars

Comment: Also, are other environment variables showing up in `process.env`?

Comment: @SudhanshuVishnoi I googled the hell of it and you simply cant access `process.env` from the client side which is where I tried to access it

Comment: Are you using react to render on server side?

Comment: @SudhanshuVishnoi no I use react but rendering client side

Comment: Yes. Environment variables are not available in the client side. In case you want this data on client side, you can pass it as a query parameter or cookie or some other way using your server.

Comment: @SidVishnoi I just had this same issue.  process.env.NODE_ENV works on the client, but not for others.  Not sure why...

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to access the environment variable on client side and this is not possible.

If you want to use environment variables on your client side application you need to set up Webpack to handle different environments.

In Webpack config files, you’ll define your global variables for each environment using [Webpack’s Define plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/).

Also don't forget to add `NODE_ENV` config variable to your heroku app and set it to `true. So you'll be sure that by accessing`process.ENV.NODE_ENV`will force runtime to use`node.js` environment.

Now you can configure you're production environment as following:

```
/* in webpack.config-prod.js */
...,
plugins: [    
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({           
    NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),      
    API_HOST: JSON.stringify(process.env.API_HOST)
  })
],
...
```

Now you can easily access you're environment variables in your client side app.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the Heroku build log, it recommends that you specify a nodejs version. If you specify a node version in your package.json, it might fix the problem.

**package.json**

```
{
...
  "engines": {
   "node": "12.13.1"
   },
...
}
```

Comment: no good, this didn't do any good for me. ENV variables are still missing