# Heroku config vars returning undefined in production

Tags: reactjs, heroku, environment-variables, cross-domain, create-react-app

I have an app that works fine locally using a `.env` file. However, when I add my variable to Heroku [as described in the heroku CRA buildpack](https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack#user-content-environment-variables) [image: correctly-entered config vars.]

But when I run my application, I get an `undefined` value.

[image: Calls failed because x-api-key undefined.]

How can I ensure that value populates properly?

Here's an example call I'm making in my app:

```
const xApiKeyHeader = { "x-api-key": process.env.REACT_APP_X_API_KEY };

const filteredProfiles = await fetch(
  `${config.url}/profile/filteredProfiles`,
  {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      ...xApiKeyHeader,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      ...this.props.filter,
      profession: this.state.professionValues,
    }),
  }
).then(...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:

Added this to my webpack config (suggested in this thread [heroku environment variables return undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51619908/heroku-environment-variables-return-undefined)):

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin(({           
    'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),      
    'process.env.REACT_APP_X_API_KEY': JSON.stringify(process.env.REACT_APP_X_API_KEY)
  })),
```

And set `NODE_ENV` to `true` in heroku config vars.